# vbscript for creating registry entries was working, now it isn't. Any ideas?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I have a vbscript that creates a registry entry on a Windows Server 2003 machine. This script has been working fine for about a year now, but recently it just stopped working. I am thinking that a windows update must have changed something, maybe a security setting, whereby this script is no longer permitted to execute. The script uses the following function to create an entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ for new ODBC connections:

```
Function CreateRegKey (sComputer, hTree, sKey)
  Dim oRegistry
  Dim lResult   
  Set oRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//" & sComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
  lResult = oRegistry.CreateKey(hTree, sKey)
  If (lResult = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then
     CreateRegKey = 0
  Else
     CreateRegKey = 1
     msgbox("Create Key " & sKey & " Failed")
  End If
  Set oRegistry = Nothing
End Function
```

This function is called as follows:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    = &H80000002
sPath = "SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\" & DataSourceName 
'Create ODBC entry
If (0 = CreateRegKey(sComputer, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, sPath)) Then
  ....
Else    
  ....
End If
```

Does anyone know of a windows update that could have caused this script to suddenly stop working? The script stops on the following line:

```
lResult = oRegistry.CreateKey(hTree, sKey)
```

It does not give an error or anything. It just stops on that line.

Anyone got an idea what is going wrong here and how I could fix it? Thanks.

EDIT: I now get the error number returned by CreateKey. It returns the following:

Err.Number: -2147023533

Err.Description: Cannot start a new logon session with an ID that is already in use

Does anyone know what is causing this and how to work around it? Thanks.

Comment: Add `On Error Resume Next` at the beginning of your function - without it error handling is off and `Err.Number` is always 0, as if no error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, Helen, for that information. I now get the error number returned by CreateKey. I have included it in an update to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description for the error code -2147023533 (0x80070553) is:

> Cannot start a new logon session with an ID that is already in use.

A search for this code and description reveals:

- [hotfix KB2283089](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2283089) for fixing the error,
- an [assumption](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/95417-kb979683-breaks-some-scripting) that the error is caused by [KB979683](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979683),
- a [suggestion to reinstall service packs](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/winserverwsus/thread/033f2c54-6df5-4779-8b05-7b268ce20916) in order to fix the error.

Give these a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Helen. I am going to give that a try. Can you tell me how the hex error code,0x80070553, is calculated from the error number -2147023533? Because searching on the hex code gives much more results. Searching on the number that Windows reported (-2147023533) gave very few useful hits in google.

Comment: 0x is a commonly used prefix for hexadecimal numbers; however in VBScript code you use the &H prefix (like in your HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE constant).